# Cell image view geting bigger when i scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I'm new to Objective-C and i want to display images in  a table view. The images are from an URL.

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"url"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-60.png"]];
```

The images are displayed correctly, but when I do scroll , they become bigger .

What i was trying to do is:

```
cell.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,10,10);
```

but it's not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the default imageView of UITableViewCell the bounds, frame properties are read-only, so you should build your own class witch extend UITableViewCell to create your own UIImageView, then if your scroll algorithm is correct all should be fine.